# Angular materal dialog does not display correct information

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, local-storage

Greeting. Angular dialog does not show me the correct information. More specifically, it shows me the information I entered in the previous times. My logic is to store information in localstorage and that works fine for me

```
  onSubmit() {
    let valuesOfForm = Object.assign(this.addForm.value,this.selectedProduct);
    localStorage.setItem("form" , JSON.stringify(valuesOfForm));
  }
```

The local storage is now my information.
before that the logic of just doing the dialogue.

```
  <div class="row">
      <button
      class="button-submit"
      mat-raised-button color="warn"
      (click)="openDialog2()">
      Posalji narudzbu</button>
    </div>


  openDialog2():void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmorderComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

I'll say it again
All this logic is found in the Order components.
Next my ConfirmorderComponent component which show information from Order component from localstorage:

```
  globalVar: string = '';
  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalVar = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
    console.log("res" , this.globalVar);
    // HERE IS WRONG RESULT. IT SHOW PREVIOUS ENTERED DATA!!!
  }


    <p>
        Product: <br> <strong>{{ globalVar.product }}</strong>
    </p>
```

I'll say it again. When I look at my Application -> Locstorage it shows the correct information, 
but somehow does not detect changes.
Maybe important i am installed  ngrx-store-localstorage  package for store persist to prevent data loss to refresh pages.

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing the data in the localstorage instead of passing it to the dialog through the data parameter?
Maybe the problem is your click event is running before the submit one, so when the dialog opens the data is stale. Have you tried opening the modal in the submit function instead?

Comment: You solved my problem... Thank you. When i set  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmorderComponent); in submit function work fine.